# How can I guarantee the existence of a method in a companion object and reference it?

Tags: scala, generics, traits, companion-object, type-bounds

Consider this example, where `Listable` is intended to mixed into the companion object of a case class. Therefore, in order to call `Writer.grid`, one must have a companion object `A` that extends `Listable[A]`, with an `implicit Writer[A]` defined within. (Say for example, to convert a list of an arbitrary `Listable` to a CSV format.)

```
trait Listable[A] {
    def list: List[A]
}

object Writer {
    def grid[A <: Listable[A]](listable: A)(implicit w: Writer[A]): String = {  
        listable.list.map(w.write(_).mkString(",")).mkString("\n")
    }
}

trait Writer[A] {
    def write(a: A): List[String]
}
```

And here's a naive implementation:

```
case class Test(id: Int, text: String)

object Test extends Listable[Test] {
    def list = List(Test(1, "test"))

    implicit val wrt = new Writer[Test] {
        def write(t: Test) = List(t.id.toString, t.text)
    }
}
```

This compiles, but cannot work because `listable: A` really refers to the object `Test`, and `A` in `w: Writer[A]` refers to the case class `Test`, so calling `Writer.grid(Test)` fails to conform to the type bounds.

I can work around this problem somewhat by ditching `Listable` and requiring an `implicit List[A]` in the signature of `grid`:

```
def grid[A](implicit w: Writer[A], list: List[A]): String = ...
```

But I'd prefer to:

1. Not require such an implicit function that could produce unexpected results.
2. Not use a special type to wrap `list`, as it will also be used elsewhere.
3. Keep the definition of the `grid` method *outside* of `Listable`.

Is it possible to re-work the signature of `Writer.grid` to make this work? (or other structural changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Engene pointed out a working solution, I just want to say that, what's really weird about your situation is that, you don't need the `listable` instance in the grid function. This fact is not that obvious from your original code, but it's pretty on the table if you see from Eugene's code, the  argument is not used at all.

So I'm guessing what you're trying to do is to have the companion object to have an instance of special instances for special purposes, maybe I'm wrong. But the name `Listable[A]` is really confusing, if you're trying to describe some trait of the companion object, you can name sth like `ListableMeta[A]`, which makes more sense.

```
trait ListableMeta[A] {
    def list: List[A]
}

object Writer {
    def grid[A : ListableMeta](implicit w: Writer[A]): String = {
        implicitly[ListableMeta[A]].list.map(w.write(_).mkString(",")).mkString("\n")
    }
}

trait Writer[A] {
    def write(a: A): List[String]
}

case class Test(id: Int, text: String)

trait InImplicit {
    implicit val injectThisToImplicits: this.type = this
}

object Test extends ListableMeta[Test] with Writer[Test] with InImplicit {
    def list = List(Test(1, "test"))

    def write(t: Test) = List(t.id.toString, t.text)
}
```

What you need to do is basically `Writer.grid[Test]` instead of passing a concrete instance, so this should work.
But the clear point here is to use typeclasses on all things, mix and match typeclasses and type bounds can cause confusion.

Comment: You're correct in that I don't need a `listable` instance for the `grid` method at all. It's meant to rely on the companion object's `list` method in order to fetch a list (and not in static way). The `listable: A` parameter was more or less a way of trying to grab a reference to the companion object (which clearly doesn't work). This is an interesting variation, but it doesn't work outside the REPL, because `Test` is a top-level object and cannot be `implicit`.

Comment: I updated the code so that it will work in the repl. As long as you get the idea, I think the rest is just impl details.

Comment: That's a nice trick. It feels a little hacky, but also allows me to define the API the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

You want something strange. Case class Test has type Test obviously, but companion object Test doesn't have any relationship to type 'Test', it has it's one type 'Test.type'.

I suggest you to make 2 proper type classes: Listable and Writer

```
  trait Listable[A] {
    def list: List[A]
  }

  object Writer {
    def grid[A : Listable : Writer](listable: A): String = {
      implicitly[Listable[A]].list.map(implicitly[Writer[A]].write(_).mkString(",")).mkString("\n")
    }
  }

  trait Writer[A] {
    def write(a: A): List[String]
  }

  case class Test(id: Int, text: String)

  object Test {
    implicit val listable: Listable[Test] = new Listable[Test] {
       def list: List[Test] = List(Test(1, "test"))
    }

    implicit val wrt: Writer[Test] = new Writer[Test] {
      def write(t: Test) = List(t.id.toString, t.text)
    }
  }

  Writer.grid(Test(123, "abc"))
```